# Hiding all untagged contents of a tag

Tags: css

I have this code, and I need to keep visible One and Four, and hide all the rest, *pipes* included. Problem is, I can't hide the pipes!

...and I cannot change the Html code.

```css
.links * {
  display: none;
}

.link-one,
.link-four {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<span class="links">
  <a href="#" class="link-one">One</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-two">Two</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-three">Three</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-four">Four</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-five">Five</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-six">Six</a>
</span>
```

Comment: set pipe inside a tag

Comment: Please don't use external code sites like codepen or jsfiddle for code that can easily be represented in a StackOverflow snippet.

Answer (score 2):

If you donot want to change the template you may need to add some script like below.

**JavaScript solution**

```js
document.querySelector('.links').innerHTML = document.querySelector('.links').innerHTML.replaceAll('|', '');
```

```css
.links * {
  display: none;
}

.links a::after {
  content: '|';
}

.links a.link-four:after {
  content: '';
}

.link-one,
.link-four {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<span class="links">
  <a href="#" class="link-one">One</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-two">Two</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-three">Three</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-four">Four</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-five">Five</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-six">Six</a>
</span>
```

**Pure CSS solution**

Donot use `"|"` in HTML instead insert it as pseudo element. This involves the template change.

```css
.links * {
  display: none;
}

.links a::after {
  content: '|';
}

.links a.link-four:after {
  content: '';
}

.link-one,
.link-four {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<span class="links">
  <a href="#" class="link-one">One</a> 
  <a href="#" class="link-two">Two</a> 
  <a href="#" class="link-three">Three</a> 
  <a href="#" class="link-four">Four</a> 
  <a href="#" class="link-five">Five</a> 
  <a href="#" class="link-six">Six</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the html...

Comment: @Manaus I have updated the solution without the template changes.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.links * {
  display: none;
}
.links a::after{
  content:'|';
  color:black;
  margin-left:5px;
  text-decoration:none !important;
  display:inline-table;
}

.link-one,
.link-four {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<span class="links">
  <a href="#" class="link-one">One</a>
  <a href="#" class="link-two">Two</a>
  <a href="#" class="link-three">Three</a>
  <a href="#" class="link-four">Four</a>
  <a href="#" class="link-five">Five</a>
  <a href="#" class="link-six">Six</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not suggested but since you can't change html that makes it difficult. a way around is to use pseudo element to hide it as you can't input pipe using pseudo element.

```css
.links * {
  display: none;
}

.link-one,
.link-four {
  display: inline;
}

.link-one::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.link-four::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<span class="links">
  <a href="#" class="link-one">One</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-two">Two</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-three">Three</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-four">Four</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-five">Five</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-six">Six</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Hide the original pipes visually by setting their font-size to `0`.
2. Reset the otherwise inherited font size for the contained links.
3. Re-create the pipes you need using a pseudo-element `::after`, place that outside of the clickable link area and give it `pointer-events: none` so clicking on it won't trigger the link.

```css
.links {
  font-size: 0;
}

.links * {
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.link-one,
.link-four {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 16px;
  position: relative;
}

.link-one::after {
  position: absolute;
  color: black !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  content: "|";
  right: -10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="links">
  <a href="#" class="link-one">One</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-two">Two</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-three">Three</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-four">Four</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-five">Five</a> |
  <a href="#" class="link-six">Six</a>
</span>
```